# How to extract file names from winrar file?

Tags: winrar

My winrar file contains about 106 files, I can't able to manual type all those file names into txt file.

Is there way to extract all those files names (I don't need file extensions) into txt file ?

Using windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use winrar from the command line to get the list of files. Open the command, move to the folder where the archive is located, then type:

```
C:\>"c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" lb test.rar > myfile.txt
```

The `l` command list the archive's files:

> l[t[a],b]     List archive contents [technical[all], bare]

The output of the command will redirect the filenames onto `myfile.txt`.